# Creating global variables in Vue vs state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, global-variables, vuex

What is the best way to create global variables in Vue? Is it to use Vuex?

I can access the Vuex state like so:

```
{{ store.$state.myvar }}
```

This is a bit messy. I would rather do:

```
{{ myvar }}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a computed property in your components:

```
computed: {
   myVar: {
      get() { return this.$store.state.myVar; },
      set(value) { this.$store.commit('updateMyVar', value); }
   },
}
```

This allows you to use it like any other property in your components.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do anything you want. You *should* try and organise your state so that "there's *a* place for everything, and everything is in its place".

Of course you can create and reference global variables in Vue. You could, say, do `var myVar = store.$state.myvar`, and you've got a global alias to your var in Vuex. But, big but, if you've chosen to use Vuex, then you kinda need to follow through on that choice. Creating aliases in global state will quickly lead to collisions and confusion. Vue is vaguely MVVM, inspired by Elm. It wants you to separate your state from your interface components. This can lead to longish paths to reference items of state, but the payoff is well worth it - you don't need to be synchronising and sharing little bits of state all over the place. Does that answer the question?

Comment: It does thanks. I think ultimately my store is getting too big so need to look at ways of breaking that down something like this https://medium.com/3yourmind/large-scale-vuex-application-structures-651e44863e2f